# Sketch discs in 3-D space

Tags: linux

I would like to draw 1000 numbers of discs in 3-D space, where each
disk have some random orientation. I know the equation of the plane
containing each disk, the center co-ordinates and also the radius of
each disk. Can anyone please help me to draw them?

Comment: I have no idea to draw them in 3-D space using the details about the information of each disk that I have. I had tried to draw them in "GNUPLOT" but failed.

Comment: It may be possible to plot it using R. I suggest you add [r] and [plot] tags to your question and also give the equations of the discs you want to plot.

Comment: Can you please tell me the detail steps in R for this? I am not familiar with R but heard about it.

Comment: We need the equations to be plotted.